# Object Sharing in Simple Multi-threaded Program

Tags: java, multithreading

### Introduction

I have written a *very* simple program as an attempt to re-introduce myself to multi-threaded programming in JAVA. The objective of my program is derived from [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html) rather neat set of articles, written by Jakob Jankov. For the program's original, unmodified version, consult the bottom of the linked article.

Jankov's program does not `System.out.println` the variables, so you cannot see what is happening. If you `.print` the resulting value you get the same results, every time (the program is thread safe); however, if you print some of the inner workings, the "inner behaviour" is different, each time.

I understand the issues involved in thread scheduling and the unpredictability of a thread's `Running`. I believe that may be a factor in the question I ask, below.

### Program's Three Parts

**The Main Class:**

```
public class multiThreadTester {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // Counter object to be shared between two threads:
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        // Instantiation of Threads:
        Thread counterThread1 = new Thread(new CounterThread(counter), "counterThread1");
        Thread counterThread2 = new Thread(new CounterThread(counter), "counterThread2");

        counterThread1.start();
        counterThread2.start(); 
    }
}
```

The objective of the above class is simply to share an object. In this case, the threads share an object of type `Counter`:

**Counter Class**

```
public class Counter {

    long count = 0;

    // Adding a value to count data member:
    public synchronized void add (long value) {
        this.count += value;
    }

    public synchronized long getValue() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

The above is simply the definition of the `Counter` class, which includes only a primitive member of type `long`.

**CounterThread Class**

Below, is the `CounterThread` class, virtually unmodified from the code provided by Jankov. The only real difference (despite my *implementing* `Runnable` as opposed to *extending* `Thread`) is the addition of `System.out.println()`. I added this to watch the inner-workings of the program.

```
public class CounterThread implements Runnable {

    protected Counter counter = null;

    public CounterThread(Counter aCounter) {
        this.counter = aCounter;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("BEFORE add - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + this.counter.getValue());
            counter.add(i);
            System.out.println("AFTER  add - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + this.counter.getValue());
        }   
    }
}
```

### Question

As you can see, the code is very simple. The above code's only purpose is to watch what happens as two threads share a thread-safe object.

My question comes as a result of the output of the program (which I have tried to condense, below). The output is hard to "get consistent" to demonstrate my question, as the spread of the difference (see below) can be quite great:

Here's the *condensed* output (trying to minimize what you look at):

```
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 0
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 0
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 1
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 1
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 3
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 3
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 6
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 6
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 10
BEFORE add - counterThread2: 0 // This BEFORE add statement is the source of my question
```

And one more output that better demonstrates:

```
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 0
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 0
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 0
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 1
BEFORE add - counterThread2: 0
AFTER  add - counterThread2: 1
BEFORE add - counterThread2: 1
AFTER  add - counterThread2: 2
BEFORE add - counterThread2: 2
AFTER  add - counterThread2: 4
BEFORE add - counterThread2: 4
AFTER  add - counterThread2: 7
BEFORE add - counterThread2: 7
AFTER  add - counterThread2: 11
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 1 // Here, counterThread1 still believes the value of Counter's counter is 1
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 13
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 13
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 16
BEFORE add - counterThread1: 16
AFTER  add - counterThread1: 20
```

My question(s):

Thread safety ensures the safe mutability of a variable, i.e. only one thread can access an object at a time. Doing this ensures that the "read" and "write" methods will behave, appropriately, only writing after a thread has released its lock (eliminating racing).

Why, despite the correct write behaviour, does `counterThread2` "believe" `Counter`'s value (**not the iterator** `i`) to still be zero? What is happening in memory? Is this a matter of the thread containing it's own, local `Counter` object?

Or, more simply, after `counterThread1` has updated the value, why does `counterThread2` not see - in this case, `System.out.println()` - the correct value? *Despite not seeing the value*, the correct value is written to the object.

Comment: As a side note: `System.out.println` is synchronized so not the best way to observe multi threaded inconsistencies because the print statement "re-synchronizes" your program.

Comment: @assylias can you elaborate, perhaps in an answer format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why, despite the correct write behaviour, does counterThread2 "believe" Counter's value to still be zero?

The threads interleaved in such a way to cause this behaviour.  Because the print statements are outside of the synchronised block, it is possible for a thread to read the counter value then pause due to is scheduling while the other thread increments multiple times.  When the waiting thread finally resumes and enters the inc counter method, the value of the counter will have moved on quite a bit and will no longer match what was printed in the BEFORE log line.

As an example, I have modified your code to make it more evident that both threads are working on the same counter.  First I have moved the print statements into the counter, then I added a unique thread label so that we can tell which thread was responsible for the increment and finally I only increment by one so that any jumps in the counter value will stand out more clearly.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // Counter object to be shared between two threads:
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        // Instantiation of Threads:
        Thread counterThread1 = new Thread(new CounterThread("A",counter), "counterThread1");
        Thread counterThread2 = new Thread(new CounterThread("B",counter), "counterThread2");

        counterThread1.start();
        counterThread2.start();
    }
}

 class Counter {

    long count = 0;

    // Adding a value to count data member:
    public synchronized void add (String label, long value) {
        System.out.println(label+ " BEFORE add - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + this.count);
        this.count += value;
        System.out.println(label+ " AFTER add - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + this.count);
    }

    public synchronized long getValue() {
        return count;
    }
}

class CounterThread implements Runnable {

    private String label;
    protected Counter counter = null;

    public CounterThread(String label, Counter aCounter) {
        this.label = label;
        this.counter = aCounter;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            counter.add(label, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.getCount()` returns the current value of `Counter`, not the value of the iterator. I am not asking about the number by which the value is incremented, but why the second thread doesn't see the new value of the `Counter` object. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Thomas make the change that I suggested, and print out a thread identifier with each println.  I will elaborate after I've done bath/bedtime with the kids.

Comment: I added your change. I still think it's a different issue. I understand why in the case of what you are saying what the issue is: the thread hasn't executed it's addition of it's local variable. However, in my issue, when the thread retrieves the current value, it believes the current value of the object (not the iterator) to be something else than what it is. I posted some more output for you to look at. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The other thread does see the changes.  Remember that the threads are capable of interleaving their calls.  I'll put together an example that makes this a bit more explicit.

Comment: @Thomas I have reworded the answer, and added a modified version of your code that aims to make its behaviour clearer.